# Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int

Tags: php

I'm trying to populate a dropdownbox from the database. The query gets displayed in the dropbox but there's an error I don't quite understand.

Here's the error:

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int

...and here's the code:

```
          <?php 
                   require_once('index.php'); //connect with the database.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM buffet";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($result != 0) {
    echo '<label>buffet:';
    echo '<select name="buffet">';
    echo '<option value="">all</option>';

    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $name = $row['buffet_id'];
        $name2 = $row['buffet_name'];
        echo '<option value="' .$name. '">' .$name2. '</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
    echo '</label>';
}


mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: oh nvm. found my mistake.
this:
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
instead of this:
if ($result != 0)

Comment: Excellent.  Consider posting your fix below as an `answer`/`solution` rather than just a comment.  This will  help others find your fix should they be in a similar predicament.  Welcome to SO by the way!

Comment: oh right. thanks for the welcome sir micky duncan.

Answer (score 0):

oh nvm. found my mistake.
Use this:

`if ($result->num_rows > 0)`

instead of this:

`if ($result != 0)`